# Render big state data in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My customer give me a table with 12k records (about 20->30MB) and then they want to show all in screen, at this time they dont want to pagination.
When the page is loaded, I call api and update new state for component but I take about 10s to finish render and when I scroll this list, it's slow too.
My question is **How do I make it faster?**

This is second case, when I try with 33k records (about 51MB), memory leak occur and white screen appear.
My question is **What is the limitation of state? Do I update state with bigger data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you need is Infinity Scroll.
It's like what Netflix or Prime Videos Does.
First You call 20 Records and when you scroll to the bottom it will call 20 more records and then so on.
So It will start with 20 and as soon as you are about to hit the bottom of the scrollbar you will call the API to fetch 20 more and add it to the old List.

Now If you have scrolled a lot and you have like 2000+ Records and It slows down, then use react-window or react-virtualized package, what this does is only render the content which you are viewing in the dom.
Check this video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhPn6hLGljU.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is best idea but at this time, I'm still thinking, where do I store 33k records in client? Or whenever I scroll I fetch range data from API, it will slow to load?

Comment: Storing 33k records in the client itself is never a good idea. The bundle size will be huge for a website and a bad experience overall.
I'm a frontend developer but I think you still can easily create a record in firebase quickly and store the records there and fetch it with API call from it.

Then use a package like react-infinity-scroller and lode 20 records at a time and keep scrolling

Comment: I absolutely know and see, I'll suggest them use pagination or show message warning with hug data because I know they dont want to pay more money. Thanks again and I'm going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the reason why it becomes slow is because the DOM you are rendering is giant, so it consumes way too much memory, hence your browser starts to hog your RAM, you should implement virtual scroll so that only visible elements are loaded in the DOM.